# Reducing the number of output neurons

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, neural-network, encog

I am trying to train a neural network to control a characters speed in 2 dimensions. x and y between -1 and 1 m/sec. Currently I split the range into 0.1 m/sec intervals so I end up with 400 output neurons (20 x values * 20 y values) if I increase the accuracy to 0.01 I end up with 40k output neurons.  Is there a way to reduce the number of output neurons?

Comment: Could you please explain some more about the network you are designing?  Why not use 2 output neurons (one for x and one for y) with continuous outputs that refer to the estimated speed for each dimension?

Comment: @MatthewSpencer , What do mean by continuous output? Do you mean I treat it as a prediction problem instead of classification? Do I just reduce the output layer to two neurons feed the outputs directly to the engine?

Comment: Greeness' answer is a strong example of what I was trying to ask.  The answer below simplifies the problem by breaking it down to two outputs with an output range of -1 to 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you are treating the problem as a **classification** problem. In the training time, you have input `X` and output `Y`. Since you are training the neural network for classification, your expected output is always like:

```
    -1  -0.9 ...  0.3  0.4  0.5 ... 1.0 m/s
Y1 = [0,  0,  ..., 1,   0,   0,  ..., 0]  // speed x component
Y2 = [0,  0,  ..., 0,   0,   1,  ..., 0]  // speed y component
Y  = [Y1, Y2]
```

That is: only one of the neurons outputs 1 for each of the speed component at x and y direction; all other neurons output 0 (in the example above, the expected output is 0.3m/s in x direction and 0.5m/s in y direction for this training instance). Actually this is probably easier to learn and has better prediction performance. But as you pointed out, it does not scale.

I think you can also treat the problem as a **regression** problem. In your network, you have one neuron for each of the speed component. Your expected output is just:

```
Y = [0.3, 0.5]  // for the same training instance you have.
```

To get an output range of -1 to 1, you have different options for the activation function in the output layer. For example, you can use

```
f(x) = 2 * (Sigmoid(x) - 0.5)
Sigmoid(x) = 1 / (1 + exp(-x))
```

Since [sigmoid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function) (x) is in (0,1), 2*(sigmoid(x) - 0.5) is in (-1,1). This change (replace multiple neurons in the output layer with two neurons) greatly decreases the complexity of the model so you might want to add more neurons in the middle layer to avoid under fitting.